# first unbind click and then bind (jquery)

Tags: jquery, onclick, bind, unbind

1.I have a onclick event on,

```
$('#locations').click(function(){
$('#train').unbind('click'); 
//do some stuff
}
```

2.Once the close button is clicked

```
$('.close').click(function(){
//do some stuff
}
```

3.Then again if I click #train

```
$('#train').bind('click', function() {
alert('train is clicked');
//do some stuff
}
```

Now the problem is #train is not firing.Is it to bind the event again on .close function?

Please suggest.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do want to re-bind the #train element after the close button is clicked?

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using? use `.on` and `.off` instead of `.bind`.

Comment: Ankit yes that's what I want to do.So once the close button/id is clicked I can click #train again.

Comment: Omar I am using jquery-1.7.1

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Looking at your question, you do not seem to bind back the `click` after you `unbind` it, so it will not fire. (Assuming you've kept the sequence of your functionality right). You'll have to do it this way:

```
//Set a function with the action you need to do after you click the train
function  trainClick() {
  alert('train is clicked');
  //do some stuff
}
```

When you're unbinding,  call `unbind` with the function name:

```
$('#locations').click(function(){
 $('#train').unbind('click',trainClick);
//do some stuff
}
```

Then, to bind the click (when `#close` is clicked), you'd use :

```
$('.close').click(function(){
  $('#train').bind('click',trainClick);
  //do some stuff
}
```

NOTE :

A better way would be use `on` and `off`, if you are using a version greater than jQuery v1.7 because, well.. then it will not work. In the code above, just replace `bind` with `on` and `unbind` with `off`.

```
$('#train').on('click',trainClick);
$('#train').off('click',trainClick);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks PC.Please give me sometime to test with it...will get back to you soon.

Answer (score 7):

**BINDING AND UNBINDING HANDLERS**

The Key is Scope.

You must declare and define the `function (trainClick(){stuff it does})` outside the event-handler so that the other buttons' functions can see it.

Below is an example.

```
function trainClick()
{
    alert("train is clicked"); //Notice this function is declared outside event handlers below
}
$('#button1').on("click", trainClick); //this calls the above function

$("#button2").on("click",function(){
    $("#button1").off("click",trainClick); //unbinds button1 from trainClick() function (event handler)
});//End Button 2 click

$("#button3").on("click",function(){
    $("#button1").on("click",trainClick); //binds button1 to trainClick() function (event handler)
});//End Button 2 click
```