# unbind and rebind click event handler on file type

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know u can do something like this

```
$('#labelID').off('click'); // unbind click event
$('#labelID').no('click',func); bind it back with a func
```

but to rebind back in my case I don't have a function, because it is the default behavior of my form upload tags, like

```
<label>upload
<input type="file">
</label>
```

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: This question already asked please check this [Bind unBind][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250308/first-unbind-click-and-then-bind-jquery

Comment: @EternalHour bind and unbind label

Comment: @Pankaj how to bind back without specify the second param which is the function? because I want to keep the default behavior of type=file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is to, disable the file selection based on some condition, in that case I think you can just disable in file input field.

```
$('input[type="file"]').prop('disabled', true)
```

Comment: @JamesLemon prop is the right choice https://forum.jquery.com/topic/please-explain-attr-vs-prop-change-in-1-6

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('input[type="file"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```