# how to diable window.onbeforeunload alert when timer is timedout

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have used window.onbeforeunload() to display an alert when the user navigates away from the page and this works fine,

```
  jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload', function (e) {
        var message = "Attention:";
        e.returnValue = message;
        return message;
    });
```

In one of the views in my project I have used a timer.The problem is that,when the timer is timed out an alert is displayed and it is followed by the window.onbeforeunload() alert.

I want only the timer alert and not both to be displayed on timer timeout.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is the browser behavior as  `beforeunload` is fired on alert. You can override this by using `unbind()` and then `bind()` again.

Comment: Thanks,please elaborate by giving an example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17250308/3639582

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Shaunak commented, you should before unbind your "hardcoded" `beforeunload` function definition :

```
jQuery(window).unbind();
```

and then redefine it:

```
jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload', function (e) {
        var message = "Attention:";
        e.returnValue = message;
        return message;
    });
```

Comment: Yes this works,but why dint it work when I did  `$(window).off('beforeunload');` OR `window.onbeforeunload=null`

Comment: Try:
`$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).off('beforeunload', function(){ });
});`

Answer (score 0):

to `unbind` an event, you need a reference to original handler.

please see below.

```js
var func = function(e) {
  var message = "Attention:";
  e.returnValue = message;
  return message;
};

jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload', func);

// Unbind 'beforeunload' after 10 seconds
setTimeout(function() {
  jQuery(window).unbind('beforeunload', func);
  alert('beforeunload unbound');
}, 10000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```