# why does jquery click event (hide/show) only work properly for the first element clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, show-hide

I have laid out my page to have a "navigation" page that consists of 3 divs that span the page, all 33% height. When you click one of the divs the other two should slide out and the information pertaining to the div you clicked should slide in in their place. This works for the first element that is clicked, no matter which one it is. But the second one I click always wraps the element to the wrong line on slide in. Any help would be much appreciated. Each div has its own click event, I have included one of the 3 below.

```
$('#contactdiv').click(function(){
  $('#aboutdiv').hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
  $('#portfoliodiv').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
  $('#contactinfo1').show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
  $('#contactinfo2').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
  $('#menutoggler').show('pulsate');
  $('#menutoggler').click(function(){
    $('#contactinfo2').hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000, function(){
        $('#portfoliodiv').show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
    });
    $('#contactinfo1').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000, function(){
        $('#aboutdiv').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
    });
    $('#menutoggler').hide('pulsate');
});
});
```

Comment: Seems you are using duplicate id, Identifiers must be __unique__

Comment: Try replacing `$('#contactdiv').click(function(){ ... });` with `$(document).on('click', '#contactdiv', function(){ ... });` ?

Comment: Because `id` values **must** be unique in the document. `$("#contactdiv")` will only select **one** element (because jQuery [effectively] optimizes it to `$(document.getElementById("contactdiv"))`).

Comment: @Barskey: Let's not suggest ways to continue using invalid markup, eh? (Not that there's anything wrong with delegation in general.)

Comment: @Satpal `id`'s must be unique

Comment: @Barskey, Yes they must be unique otherwise HTML document is invalid

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Invalid markup? There's a lot of instances where `.click()` doesn't trigger, I suggested it in a comment because I didn't know if it was the solution.

Comment: I have two other click events listening to the other two unique id tags. they are all unique.

Edit: there is a 'menutoggle' button that appears once you click one, and when you click that the page should go back to the original layout.

Comment: @Barskey: The same `id` on multiple elements is invalid markup. (Well, markup for an invalid document.)

Comment: @NolanJames: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: You are changing the menutoggler element's click handler dynamically based on which div is clicked, and you're doing this directly using `$('#menutoggler').click(foo)` which will add up the event handlers, not replace them.
Try binding/unbinding the handlers, like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250308/first-unbind-click-and-then-bind-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming, you added the below piece of code in all (`contactdiv`, `portfoliodiv`, `aboutdiv`) of the click handlers.

```
$('#menutoggler').click(function(){})
```

So everytime you click one of the 3 menu divs, you are **adding** one click handler on `#menutoggler`.

Say you clicked on `contactdiv` and then `aboutdiv`. Now, if you click on `menutoggler`, the click handle on `#menutoggler` inside `contactdiv` will ALSO be executed along with the click handle on `#menutoggler` inside `aboutdiv` (sorry if i didn't explained it properly)

What you should probably do is write separate click handlers based on "task"

1. click handler on either of `contactdiv`, `portfoliodiv`, `aboutdiv`
2. toggle `menutoggler`

HTML

```
<div id="contactdiv" class="menuItem"></div>
<div id="portfoliodiv" class="menuItem"></div>
<div id="aboutdiv" class="menuItem"></div>
```

JS

```
var ids = ['contactdiv', 'portfoliodiv', 'aboutdiv'];
var activeMenu;
function hideOtherMenus(id) {
  var otherMenus = ids.filter(function(i) {
    return i !== id;
  });
  otherMenus.forEach(function(i) {
    // you probably need more if/else conditions if you want to set the correct direction
    $('#' + i).hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);   
  });
}
function showInfo(id) {
  if(id === 'contactdiv') {
    ['contactinfo1', 'contactinfo2'].forEach(function(i) {
      // you probably need more if/else conditions if you want to set the correct direction
      $('#' + i).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);     
    });
  }
  // do the same for portfolio and about
}


$('.menuItem').click(function(){
  activeMenu = this.id;
  hideOtherMenus(activeMenu);
  showInfo(activeMenu);
  $('#menutoggler').show('pulsate');
});

$('#menutoggler').click(function(){
  if (activeMenu === 'contactdiv') {
    $('#contactinfo2').hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000, function(){
        $('#portfoliodiv').show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
    });
    $('#contactinfo1').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000, function(){
        $('#aboutdiv').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
    });
  }
  // do the same for portfolio and about
  $('#menutoggler').hide('pulsate');
});
```

Note: you could handle the `if/else` conditions better if you name the divs properly.

Comment: Thanks Venugopal! That makes a lot of sense. I was thinking that the problem was that the click handlers were adding up but couldnt figure out why and how to fix it. Ill try this and let you know if it fixes the issue!!

Comment: This works like a charm!!! Thanks again. I spent way too long messing with this and you helped me fix it in 10 minutes. I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Great! you may [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that you believe is the best solution to your problem.